# Getting PHPQuery results as DOMDocument objects?

Tags: php, dom

Right now, I'm getting results from PHPQuery as strings and then using DOMDocument to parse the string. Since PHPQuery uses DOMDocument, can I get results from PHPQuery as DOMDocument objects? How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get a `phpQueryObject`, you can access the `DomDocument` with the public function `getDOMDocument()`

```
pq('whatever')->getDocument()->getDOMDocument();
```

Comment: This seems to return the entire document. I should've been clearer in the question: I only want the matched elements in DOMDocument. For `pq('whatever')->getDocument()->getDOMDocument();`, I only want the `whatever` part of the DOMDocument.